# $w(K) = |K|$ for scattered compacta

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that for scattered $T_2$ compacta, the weight agrees with the cardinality. This should be a standard fact in topology, but I failed to find a proof on the literature.

Here's my attempt: let $K$ be scattered and let $\alpha$ be its height; namely, the least ordinal such that $K^{(\alpha+1)} = \varnothing$. Then, quite clearly, $K=\bigcup_{\beta \leq \alpha} K^{(\beta)} \setminus K^{(\beta+1)}$. The key fact is that every point $x\in K^{(\beta)} \setminus K^{(\beta+1)}$ possesses an open neighborhood $V_x$ so that

- $V_x \cap K^{(\beta)}=\{x\}$ (just by the fact that $x\in K^{(\beta)} \setminus K^{(\beta+1)}$)
- $V_x \cap K^{(\beta+1)} = \varnothing$  (because $x\notin K^{(\beta+1)}$ and $K^{(\beta+1)}$ is a closed set of a $T_3$ space)

Now:

*1. $V_x$ cannot be written as any union $\bigcup_{y\in Y}V_y$ when $Y\subseteq K \setminus \{x\}$.*

Indeed, if for some $x\in K^{(\beta)}\setminus K^{(\beta+1)}$ and some $Y\subseteq  K\setminus\{x\}$ we would have $V_x=\bigcup_{y\in Y} V_y$, let $$\hat{\gamma} = \min\{\gamma: V_y \cap K^{(\gamma)} = \varnothing \ \forall y\in Y\}$$
then $\hat{\gamma}\not\leq \beta$ (because then $x\in V_x$ but $x\notin  \bigcup_{y\in Y} V_y$) and $\hat{\gamma} \not >\beta$ either (because then $V_y \cap K^{(\beta+1)} \neq \varnothing$ for at least one $y\in Y$).

*2. Any base for the topology on $K$ must contain some $V_x$ for every $x\in K$.*

Let $x\in K^{(\beta)} \setminus K^{(\beta+1)}$ and assume $V_x = \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$. Then one of them, say $B_j$, contains $x$, but by construction $B_j \cap K^{(\beta)} = \{x\}$ and $B_j \cap K^{(\beta+1)}=\varnothing$.

And these two would yield $w(K)\geq|K|$ (the other inequality is standard for compact spaces).

Comment: See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827753/compact-scattered-spaces-x-with-wxx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already knew that post, but unfortunately I seem not to have access to such books. So in the end it seemed easier to come with a "proof" of my own.